# ImportError: cannot import name 'RolloutWorker'(ray.rllib)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray

I want to import one of agents in ray.rllib, 'ddpg', but some error pop out.

Anyone can help me??

I use google colab.

[image]

Comment: the error says you need to installl the package first. You can proceed with the command !pip install ray

Comment: @MicheleGiglioni Hi. Thanks for your answer. But I already run these codes: "!pip install ray", "!pip install ray[rllib]", "!pip install ray[debug]".

Comment: I tried following commands in Google collab: 1) !pip install ray, 2) !pip install ray[rllib], 3) !pip install ray[debug], 4) import ray, 5) from ray import tune, 6) import ray.rllib.agents.ddpg as ddpg. It didn't prompt any error to me. I would suggest you relaunch Google collab and try again.

Comment: @Raghvendra Hi. Thanks for your answer. run "from ray.rllib.agents.ddpg import ddpg" command, but same error pop out.

Comment: @PeterKim I just updated my comment. Please relook and let me know.

Comment: @Raghvendra Thank you so so so so so so MUCH!! I try 1) to 6) step by step, and error does not occur.